# Gradle: publish an artifact with a subset of files/dependencies of a project

Tags: gradle, publish, artifactory

I am lost in all these plugins :(

What I have so far, looks something like this:

```
artifactory {
  contextUrl = artifactoryUrl
  publish {
    repository {
      repoKey = project.repo
      username = artifactoryUser
      password = artifactoryPassword
      maven = true

    defaults {
      publications('mavenJava')
    }
  }
}

version = "${majorVersion}${buildNumber}${snapshot}"
publishing {
  publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java
      artifact sourceJar {
        classifier = 'sources'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am sorry, I did write this myself, but, mostly by copying and pasting things from various examples I found on the web, so I am not sure what this is actually doing :(

Surprisingly, this works: I can do `gradle artifactoryPublish`, and uploads a pom file and two jars (classes and sources) to artifactory.

But, I need to modify it, so that I can publish a subset of the project as a different artifact, and only include the dependencies that it requires. 
I managed to build a jar file:

```
 task utilJar(type: Jar) {
   from sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
   include '**/util/*.class'
   baseName 'basic-util'
 }
```

I also defined a Configuration with a subset of dependencies:

```
 configurations {
    util 
 }

 dependencies {
   util "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4"
   util "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
 }

 artifacts {
   util utilJar
 }
```

This is where I get stuck. How do I get this new artifact published?

I tried following the same strategy:

```
publishing {
  publications {
    mavenUtil(MavenPublication) {
      from components.java
      artifact utilJar {
        classifier = 'util'
      }
    }
  }
} 

artifactory {
 defaults {
   publications('mavenUtil')
 }
}
```

(this is in a subproject, so I need it do be incremental) 
This does not work: 
`Could not find method defaults() for arguments [build_8axxghkylu3559p5lal6spy1u$_run_closure7$_closure11@38abcbd4]`

But, even if it did, it would still be not be quite what I need, because I don't know how I could then publish a particular artifact: the only way I could ever publish anything at all is `gradle artifactoryPublish`, but that does not ask me which artifacts to publish. Will it publish everything every time?

As you can see, I am hopelessly lost here :(
Could someone with a clue please show me the light?

**UPDATE** So, I removed the last `artifactory` closure from the build, and now I not getting the error, but still can't get it to do what I need. 
My artifactory seems to be not in good mood right now, so I am publishing locally.

`gradle publishToMavenLocal` creates a single artifact as before, but adds my new "-util" jar to it. This is *not at all* what I want. I need a new, separate artifact, with that jar file, and its own set of dependencies.

Here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:repositories I found a suggestion, that "The created task is named “publish«PUBNAME»PublicationTo«REPONAME»Repository”". This does not seem to to be true, because `gradle publishUtilMavenPublicationToMavenLocalRepository` (with all the case variations I could think off) says that there is no such task. :(

Comment: Try `gradle tasks --all` to see all available tasks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [set me up](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Artifactory#UsingArtifactory-SetMeUp) feature? It available for all version of Artifactory. It should provide a good starting point to configure you gradle project to work with Artifactory.

Specifically for Gradle it can assist you with generating the relevant configuration according to the repositories you wish to resolve / publish from / to, defining the relevant dependencies to install the jfrog plugin etc.

Comment: Yeah, I used that to get to what I have now (in the beginning of my post). Not sure how it can help with what I need to do now.